# Does glGenTexture only work in the main?

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, opengl

I have loaded textures into openGL before, worked fine. But this time I wanted to load a texture within a constructor of my rendering class. (im using MVC with abstract base classes as interfaces). I was originally trying to load a png file rather than a bmp as I did before so i assumed it was something to do with that, but when i went back to my bmp code it still didn't work. So a hunch I moved the bmp texture code into the main(of the same MVC project) and it works. The actual part that wasnt working was:

```
GLuint textureId;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureId); 
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    //Map the image to the texture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,//This bit!!               
                 0,                           
                 GL_RGB,                      
                 image->width, image->height,  
                 0,                            
                 GL_RGB, 
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,                                 
                 image->pixels);
```

if I stepped through the program I noticed that textureID stayed the same (didnt change to 1 becuase no texture was being mapped to it)

Why is this? and can it be fixed?

Comment: glGenTextures certainly works outside main, too. It works whenever a valid context is bound. What it does is merely reserve a number for use as texture identifier, not more.

Comment: @Damon: I see... So why would exactly the same code not work in my constructor but will work in the main?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When is the constructor being called? You need a valid OpenGL context to make any GL call. A usual error is to create objects at the global scope, and that means the object is constructed at program start, before main() is called, and at that point there is no OpenGL context created yet.

Comment: That will be exactly it! it is before the main, and in a global object. thanks alot! (it doesn't tell you these things in the red book)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you made `textureId` into a local variable, which disappears when the current function (the constructor) finishes.  Try a class member variable if you want it to live longer.

Comment: I believe I did. This was just to show what code was going wrong with minimal code. I created it in the header(private, also tried it as public), assigned it zero using an initiation list. Also wouldn't I see the textureID change to 1 within the constructor?(before the end of the constructor's scope) I was rendering it in a different method to the constructor so it would have gave an undefined error. PS sorry i should have included this in the question